# Running an android activity in background

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor, android-service, android-activity

I need to connect to database to read data. So I'm using the startManagingCursor() function. But my working class is not extending Activity. That causes failure of the function. Then I moved the function to an another Activity, and created the new Activity from my application. This time I got the black screen, because when I created the new Activity, it comes to frontground.

So here are my questions:

1- Is there a way to call the startManagingCursor within a Service? (Probably No, but I need to be sure.) If yes how?

2- If the first questions answer is no,  can I run an Activity in the background like a Service. If yes how?

3- If the second questions answer is no too, is there any way to make read query except using cursor? If yes what is it, and how should I use it?

4- If the third question answer is no too, what can I do to read data from Sqlite Database without using an Activity?

Platform : Android 2.2

Comment: use async task and read the data  check the link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [`CursorLoader` class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html).

Comment: It comes with API level 11, I use 8.

Comment: @juliadream: Use the compatibility package